# setImageBitmap not displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

On click, my app gives choice between camera and gallery and that picture is then displayed in an ImageView. I originally tried to display the full image and then tried to use the bitmap way but nothing works. I just get a blank ImageView. Please give me some guidance as to what I'm doing wrong and ask for clarifications if necessary:

*Camera/gallery photo code:*

```
Uri outputFileUri;
private void openImageIntent() {
    // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    final String fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }
    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 0);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent returnIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(resultCode, requestCode, returnIntent);
    if(requestCode == 0) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final boolean isCamera;
            if(returnIntent == null) {
                isCamera = true;
            }
            else
            {
                final String action = returnIntent.getAction();
                if(action == null) {
                    isCamera = false;
                }
                else {
                    isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }
            Uri selectedImageUri;
            if(isCamera) {
                selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                mainImage.setImageURI(selectedImageUri); //trying full image
            }
            else {
                selectedImageUri = returnIntent == null ? null : returnIntent.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                    mainImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //trying bitmap
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take image from camera you can go with this process:

```
public void fromCamera(){

    String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
    File file = new File(path,"IMG_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mPicCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPicCaptureUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

}
```

And if you want image from gallery then :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_file)), REQUEST_GALLERY);
```

On your onActivityResult you can get the image path of selected one and set image in image view....

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            //do set your image here


        }else if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA){

            if(mPicCaptureUri!=null){
                //do try to set image here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

don't forgrt to define mPicCaptureUri at the top as:

```
private Uri mPicCaptureUri = null;
```

You can take idea from above code ..it might help you

Answer (score 5):

### your code is 2000000000000000% ok i test it myself

Your problem is your ImageView can't show image because of image size. I try this code with ImageView like this

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mainImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />
```

If you use height and width with dp like this

```
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
```

You need to compress the Bitmap to show it in ImageView.
Edit your  code to conversion

```
if(isCamera) {
                selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);//You can use this bitmap if need full image to further use 
                    Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,  600 ,600, true);//this bitmap2 you can use only for display
                    mainImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap2); //trying full image
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else {
                selectedImageUri = returnIntent == null ? null : returnIntent.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,  600 ,600, true);
                    mainImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //trying bitmap
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you could use Picasso Library :D

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(item.getPhotoUri())
    .resize(512,512)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)
    .error(R.drawable.error_image)
    .into(photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens due to image being too big to be rendered by bitmap within that span of nano second during runtime, so you won't see it. Use a library called Glide. It solved all my image issues in Android including performance when there are hundreds of images to be displayed in a single list or grid.